# How to update ItemSource of ContextMenu with using MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, contextmenu, itemsource

I have a ContextMenu and I am trying to bind a list from my ViewModel class. I set this List with using two different Methods. `OnZonesReceived` method is triggered when changes are made and `OnItemReceived`method is triggered when selected tab item changed. In this project I have tabItems and each tabItem has its own DesignerCanvas.

The problem is `Zones` is updated when selected tab Item changed but it is not updated when DesignerCanvas updated while `OnZonesReceived` method is triggered and The input "canvas" has the correct `Zones` List.

### ResouceDictionary

```
<MenuItem Header="Zones" ItemsSource="{Binding Zones, Mode=TwoWay}">
            <MenuItem.DataContext>
                <viewModel:ZoneViewModel/>
            </MenuItem.DataContext>
            <MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type dataModel:ZoneModel}" >
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
        </MenuItem>
```

### ViewModel

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using Core.Media;
using PropulsimGUI.Controls;
using PropulsimGUI.DataModel;
using PropulsimGUI.Utilities;

namespace PropulsimGUI.ViewModel
{
    public class ZoneViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public ZoneViewModel()
        {
            Messenger.Default.Register<ClosableTab>(this, OnItemReceived);
            Messenger.Default.Register<DesignerCanvas>(this, OnZonesReceived, "Zone");
        }

        private void OnZonesReceived(DesignerCanvas canvas)
        {
            Zones = canvas.Zones;
        }

        public void OnItemReceived(ClosableTab item)
        {
            Zones = item.DesignerCanvas.Zones;
        }

        private List<ZoneModel> _zones;

        public List<ZoneModel> Zones
        {
            get { return _zones; }

            set
            {
                _zones = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Zones");
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyThatChanged)
        {
            //checking if event is not null than raise event and pass
            //in propperty name that has changed
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyThatChanged));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the question here? Because "why Zones = canvas.Zones; doesnt work" is not a question.

Answer (score 0):

You give not enough information, but as I can see, if event `OnZonesReceived` is called and code `Zones = item.DesignerCanvas.Zones;` works, then the only reason why `Zones = canvas.Zones;` doesn't work is that `canvas.Zones` is the same object, in this case despite `RaisePropertyChanged("Zones");` binding to 
`Zones` will not be updated. I.e. code

```
Zones.Add(new ZoneModel());
Zones=Zones;
```

will NOT update the ItemsSource.

You solution can be:

```
private void OnZonesReceived(DesignerCanvas canvas)
{
    Zones = new List<ZoneModel>(canvas.Zones);
}
```